# How to keep IOIO connected when android screen goes off?

Tags: java, android, usb, ioio

I am using the following code with IOIO to act as a motion detector, the problem is the IOIO is disconnected whenever my phone screen goes off! I do not want the screen to stay on all the time to keep the IOIO connected!

any solution please?

```
    package com.LookHin.ioio_pir_motion_sensor;
    
    import ioio.lib.api.AnalogInput;
    import ioio.lib.api.DigitalOutput;
    import ioio.lib.api.exception.ConnectionLostException;
    import ioio.lib.util.BaseIOIOLooper;
    import ioio.lib.util.IOIOLooper;
    import ioio.lib.util.android.IOIOActivity;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.graphics.Color;
    import android.media.Ringtone;
    import android.media.RingtoneManager;
    import android.net.Uri;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.Menu;
    import android.view.MenuItem;
    import android.widget.TextView;
    import android.widget.Toast;
    import android.widget.ToggleButton;
    
    public class MainActivity extends IOIOActivity {
    
    private ToggleButton toggleButton1;
    private TextView textView1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        
        textView1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        toggleButton1 = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.toggleButton1);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }
    
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
    {
        switch (item.getItemId())
        {
        case R.id.action_about:
            //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Show About", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            
            Intent about = new Intent(this, AboutActivity.class);
            startActivity(about);
            
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    } 
    
    
    class Looper extends BaseIOIOLooper {
        
        private DigitalOutput digital_led0;
        private AnalogInput deigital_input;
        int i = 0;
        
        private float InputStatus;
        
        @Override
        protected void setup() throws ConnectionLostException {
            
            digital_led0 = ioio_.openDigitalOutput(0,true);
            deigital_input = ioio_.openAnalogInput(45);
                            
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "IOIO Connect", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
            
        }

        @Override
        public void loop() throws ConnectionLostException {
            
            
            try{
                digital_led0.write(!toggleButton1.isChecked());

                InputStatus = deigital_input.getVoltage();
                
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        
                        textView1.setText(String.format("%.02f",InputStatus)+" v.");
                        
                        if(InputStatus >= 3.0){
                            textView1.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
                            
                            if (i == 0){
                            Uri notification = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
                            Ringtone r = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(getApplicationContext(), notification);
                            r.play();
                            i = 1;
                            };
                            
                        }else{
                            textView1.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
                            i = 0;
                        }
                        
                    }
                });
                
                Thread.sleep(100);
    
            }catch(InterruptedException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            
        }
    }
    

    @Override
    protected IOIOLooper createIOIOLooper() {
        return new Looper();
    }
        
}
```

Comment: Possibly a [partial wake lock](https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/wakelock.html#cpu)?

Comment: I will take a look for this, thanks Steven.

Answer (score 0):

Option 1) Lock the screen so it always stays awake

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
```

Option 2) Fix your response to onPause().

When the screen goes off the onPause() method is called and you should handle it as otherwise your activity will be closed.

```
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    // Your code
    super.onPause();
}
```

The onPause() normally calls the ioio.disconnect() so this should be overrode.

Answer (score 0):

[IOIOService](https://github.com/ytai/ioio/tree/master/software/applications/HelloIOIOService) let´s you run your code on the background even if application goes to the background.